# Tell APK to install a flagged package

Tags: package-management, alpine-linux

I am trying to install `megatools` on an Alpine Linux container in Docker. This package is flagged because a new version is available.

How can I force `apk` to install this package despite the flag? I tried specifying the version explictely, but it always fail.

Without specifying the version explicitely:

```
/ # apk add megatools
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  megatools (missing):
    required by: world[megatools]
```

With the version:

```
/ # apk add megatools=1.9.98-r3
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  megatools (missing):
    required by: world[megatools=1.9.98-r3]
```

All of this happens in stock `alpine:latest` Docker image.

Package page on the Alpine repo browser is here: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/megatools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the package flags (I'm not familiar to package flagging with `apk`), but it seems to be a matter of missing repositories.

The `megatools` package is found in the `edge/testing` repository, which you're currently missing (note the *Branch* and *Repository* fields in the package description page, also indicated in the URL).

You'll also need the `edge/main` repository, for satisfying the `libcrypto` dependency.

In summary:

```
echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main >> /etc/apk/repositories
echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk update
apk add megatools
```

Note that `edge` contains the latest development packages, and are not official stable versions, so use them with care. This is especially true for `testing` packages.

More on the edge repository: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your method in a Dokcer container and I was able to install megatools. However in the end I used another solution (I use megatools in a Gitlab CI, and I just commited the megatools exe in the repo's tool directory).